# How to get list of fixed issues during a sonar scan

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-4.5

After every sonar scan we can see the list of newly added issues in both portal and Scan logs like shown below. Iam able to get the list of newly added issues using the Rest API

http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?createdAfter=2015-08-15

Here we can see 18 Major issues have been fixed , and being shown in green.
Is there any way to find out the list of fixed issues in a particular scan.
Using API or any other approach

[image]

```
[sonar:sonar] 07:06:13.946 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/ICDP_NOV_2015
[sonar:sonar] 07:06:14.012 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.issuesreport.ReportJob 
[sonar:sonar] 07:06:21.327 INFO  - HTML Issues Report generated: /hosting/workspace/Sonar_20151102/make/sonar_deploy/.sonar/issues-report/issues-report.html
[sonar:sonar] 07:06:21.494 INFO  - Light HTML Issues Report generated: /hosting/workspace/Sonar_20151102/make/sonar_deploy/.sonar/issues-report/issues-report-light.html
[sonar:sonar] 07:06:21.497 INFO  - 
[sonar:sonar] 
[sonar:sonar] -------------  Issues Report  -------------
[sonar:sonar] 
[sonar:sonar]        +27 issues
[sonar:sonar] 
[sonar:sonar]        +20 major
[sonar:sonar]         +7 minor
[sonar:sonar] 
[sonar:sonar] -------------------------------------------
[sonar:sonar] 
[sonar:sonar] 
[sonar:sonar] 07:06:21.497 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.issueassign.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
[sonar:sonar] 07:06:21.902 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
[sonar:sonar] 07:06:22.361 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.pl
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not yet possible to track the remediated technical debt. You can only track for the time being the new technical debt.

Comment: Thanks freddy! Is there any alternative approach to that? Like creating users and assigning defects or SCM plugin.

Comment: is this still the case?

Comment: Sonar rest api has an endpoint to get list of fixed issues and then use the date to filter.

Answer (score 2):

There is one possible way of doing that, but not the best way

Once you call http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search and you will get an array like below,

```
 {  
       "paging":{  
          "pageIndex":1,
          "pageSize":100,
          "total":1
       },
       "issues":[  
          {  
             "key":"01fc972e-2a3c-433e-bcae-0bd7f88f5123",
             "component":"com.github.kevinsawicki:http-request:com.github.kevinsawicki.http.HttpRequest",
             "project":"com.github.kevinsawicki:http-request",
             "rule":"checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.MagicNumberCheck",
             "status":"RESOLVED",
             "resolution":"FALSE-POSITIVE",
             "severity":"MINOR",
             "message":"'3' is a magic number.",
             "line":530,
             "textRange":{  
                "startLine":81,
                "endLine":81,
                "startOffset":0,
                "endOffset":134
             },
             "author":"Developer 1",
             "effort":"2h1min",
             "creationDate":"2013-05-13T17:55:39+0200",
             "updateDate":"2013-05-13T17:55:39+0200",
             "tags":[  
                "bug"
             ],
             "type":"RELIABILITY",
             "comments":[  
                {  
                   "key":"7d7c56f5-7b5a-41b9-87f8-36fa70caa5ba",
                   "login":"john.smith",
                   "htmlText":"Must be &quot;final&quot;!",
                   "markdown":"Must be \"final\"!",
                   "updatable":false,
                   "createdAt":"2013-05-13T18:08:34+0200"
                }
             ],
             "attr":{  
                "jira-issue-key":"SONAR-1234"
             },
             "transitions":[  
                "unconfirm",
                "resolve",
                "falsepositive"
             ],
             "actions":[  
                "comment"
             ]
          }
       ],
       "components":[  
          {  
             "key":"com.github.kevinsawicki:http-request:src/main/java/com/github/kevinsawicki/http/HttpRequest.java",
             "enabled":true,
             "qualifier":"FIL",
             "name":"HttpRequest.java",
             "longName":"src/main/java/com/github/kevinsawicki/http/HttpRequest.java",
             "path":"src/main/java/com/github/kevinsawicki/http/HttpRequest.java"
          },
          {  
             "key":"com.github.kevinsawicki:http-request",
             "enabled":true,
             "qualifier":"TRK",
             "name":"http-request",
             "longName":"http-request"
          }
       ],
       "rules":[  
          {  
             "key":"checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.MagicNumberCheck",
             "name":"Magic Number",
             "status":"READY",
             "lang":"java",
             "langName":"Java"
          }
       ],
       "users":[  
          {  
             "login":"admin",
             "name":"Administrator",
             "active":true,
             "email":"admin@sonarqube.org"
          }
       ]
    }
```

What you can do is read all the objects and check the updated date (`"updateDate":"2013-05-13T17:55:39+0200"`) is greater than your analysis date (which you can get by SonrQube webHooks). Then read the status as well to check the issue is fixed (`"status":"RESOLVED"`)

Once an issue is fixed the `"updateDate"` variable will be updated.

when you call the API http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search you can use the parameter `statuses=RESOLVED,CLOSED` if you want only the fixed issues. You can add this parameter to reduce the number of results you get and optimize your process.

Refer https://codeen-app.euclid-ec.org/sonar/web_api/api/issues for more details.